# What is basic Difference Between Type.GetType() and Type.GetElementType()

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I can understand the `Type.GetType()` 's Scenario which the Object's type will be got, but what is `Type.GetElementType()` and what does it do?

Can anyone explain it in a clear way?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.type.getelementtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx - the remarks section is wrong, but the code example seems clear enough. What don't you understand in it?

Comment: bit confused.. whether it will return the Base Class Type...

Comment: Why would it? Anyway, what's so hard in typing these 10 lines for yourself to try it out?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Type.GetElementType` is used for arrays, pointers, and by-ref parameter types. For example:

```
object value = new int[100];
Console.WriteLine(value.GetType()); // System.Int32[]
Console.WriteLine(value.GetType().GetElementType()); // System.Int32
```

Or:

```
public void Foo(ref int x) {}
...
var method = typeof(Test).GetMethod("Foo");
var parameter = method.GetParameters()[0];
Console.WriteLine(parameter.ParameterType); // System.Int32&
Console.WriteLine(parameter.ParameterType.GetElementType()); // System.Int32
```

As for when you'd *use* them - well, it depends what you're using reflection for to start with.

Comment: Thank you @Jon Skeet... I understood. Hierarchical difference may be.. it gives the Original Type..

Comment: if the `GetType()` already returned `System.Int32` then the `GetElementType()` will be null? isn't it?

Comment: @Gokul: Why not try it? (After checking what the documentation says, of course...)

Answer (score 2):

`GetElementType` is for use with arrays, not other generic classes

For more detail [Refer This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getelementtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

[`Type.GetElementType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getelementtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) gets the Type of the object encompassed or referred to by the current array, pointer or reference type. For example:

```
using System;
class TestGetElementType 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        int[] array = {1,2,3};
        Type t = array.GetType();
        Type t2 = t.GetElementType();
        Console.WriteLine("The element type of {0} is {1}.",array, t2.ToString());
        TestGetElementType newMe = new TestGetElementType();
        t = newMe.GetType();
        t2 = t.GetElementType();
        Console.WriteLine("The element type of {0} is {1}.", newMe, t2==null? "null" : t2.ToString());
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
The element type of System.Int32[] is System.Int32.
The element type of TestGetElementType is null.
```